# Extra argument in rpart.plot and prp function not working for anova method: solution or alternative

Tags: r, rpart

I have an issue with the "extra" argument from the rpart.plot function. Basically, only "extra=1" works, all other numeric values from 2 to 4 throw an error. Using the mtcars dataset, here is the code I have that works:

1. Creating the tree:

   ```
   library(rpart)
   library(rpart.plot)
   data("mtcars")

   mytree <- rpart(cyl ~ ., mtcars,control=rpart.control(minsplit=1, 
   minbucket=1, cp = 0.001), method = "anova")
   ```
2. Ploting the tree, using either the rpart.plot or the prp function:

   ```
   rpart.plot(mytree, extra=1)
   prp(mytree, type=4, extra=1)
   ```

Now, changing the "extra=1" to "extra=2" (or 3, or 4) does not work. The error message I get is:

```
Error: extra=4 is illegal (for method="anova")
```

Now, I chose the "anova" method because the "class" method does not seem to be working with my dataset (R studio crashes basically) while the anova method works greatly.

1. Can I solve this solution with the anova method ? If yes, how?
2. Should I use another method and then understand why it crashes? The dataset I use is not crazy big so I have a hard time to see what I could do to solve this.

In advance thanks a lot for all the help !

Cheers,
D.

Comment: could you provide the `y` from your data set. With `mtcars` the problem you state can not be replicated.

Comment: The extra=4 option only works for class models, because "probability per class of observations in the node" (to quote the rpart.plot help page) doesn't make sense for an anova model.  As implied by user missuse in the comment above, extra=4, method="class" works with the mtcars data, so if you can post your data (or email me directly) we may be able to figure out why R studio is misbehaving with your data - that seems to be the real issue here.

Comment: Dear Stephen, thank you very much for your answer! I will send you the data asap. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @missuse: thank you for your answer. The problem remained with cyl ~ mpg (for example) but now I know what is my next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, "The extra=4 option only works for class models, because "probability per class of observations in the node" (to quote the rpart.plot help page) doesn't make sense for an anova model." So the problem is more why the class method is not working for my dataset.